# Is it possible to add menu items when popupScreen is opened in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, user-interface

```
public class xyz extends PopupScreen{
}
```

Now I want to add menu items when this screen popup. I tried adding menu items as in the case of mainscreen but it is not working in the popupScreen.

Comment: You want to add menuItems to the previous screen when the present popupScreen is popup?

Answer (score 1):

On the popup screen menu can not be added because the problem is that for example:-

I have a mainscreen call as sample screen and on sample screen let say I have save and cancel menu, now from main screen I push a popup screen. Now if I say i want save and cancel menu also on popup screen then blackberry cannot able to recognize which menu is that, either it is of sample screen or it is of popup screen.

So, that's why blackberry does not support menu on popup screen.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this sample class like your requirement:

```
public class SimpleScreen extends MainScreen
{
Font font;
private MenuItem saveItem;
private ButtonField buttonField;
public SimpleScreen() 
{
    font=Font.getDefault().derive(Font.ITALIC|Font.BOLD, 20);
    createGUI();        
    this.setFont(font);
}

private void createGUI()
{
    buttonField=new ButtonField("Click For Popup",Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
    buttonField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() 
    {
        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ScreenPopup(SimpleScreen.this));
        }
    });
    add(buttonField);

}

public void addMenuItemToMenu()
{
    if(saveItem==null)
    {
        saveItem=new MenuItem("Save",100,101) 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Status.show("Clicked on Save Menu", 500);
            }
        };
        addMenuItem(saveItem);
    }
}           
}

class ScreenPopup extends PopupScreen
{
private SimpleScreen simpleScreen;
public ScreenPopup(SimpleScreen simpleScreen) 
{
    super(new HorizontalFieldManager(),PopupScreen.DEFAULT_CLOSE);
    this.simpleScreen=simpleScreen;
    this.add(new LabelField("ADDING Menu By Clicking the Back Button"));
}

public boolean onClose() 
{
    simpleScreen.addMenuItemToMenu();
    return super.onClose();
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i make a custom dialog box by extending mainscreen ...........................